# MSI Control Center doesn't save fan speed settings

Tags: motherboard, fan

My problem is that MSI Control Center, for *fxa990-gd65* motherboard, doesn't save the fan speed settings and resets them every time you shut down / restart the PC.

It even has the save/restore settings feature which allows saving to a file, but that doesn't work either. As far as I know, MSI never bothered to release an update for this version of Control Center.

My question is there any fix to this that I failed to find? (after countless searching on Google and only seeing reports of the same problem without any solution), or should I just replace my motherboard and never buy any MSI motherboards ever again?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already found the correct solution, and did not sell your motherboard already!

The control center is only for temporarily changes to your motherboard. To keep the changes after the reboot you have to change it inside the BIOS (click bios II will work aswell).

To change the fan speed inside Click bios II:

1. Go to settings
2. Click on Hardware Monitor
3. Choose the correct
   values for the CPU speed. In my case 0% minimum speed was not
   accepted and automatically resets to 50%. 12,5% is accepted though.